# Nuget package manager: can not install/update packages in my visual studio solution

Tags: windows, nuget, .net-7.0

I try to install a nuget package in my software project in visual studio 2022 (Version 17.4.4) with PM-console with the command:

Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool -ProjectName

I get the following error message:

Sorry the original error message is in german language
Install-Package : Ungültige Wiederherstellungseingabe. Die erforderliche Eigenschaft "ProjectName" fehlt.
Eingabedateien: Drive:<PathToProject><Another project in soulution>.csproj.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1

- Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool -ProjectName
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
  ```

The Error message means:
Install-Package : Invalid restore input. The required property "ProjectName" is missing.
Input files: Drive:<PathToProject><Another project in solution>.csproj.
In Line:1 Character:1

Nuget version please see here:

Name             : Package Manager Host
Version          : 6.4.0.111
InstanceId       : 5d8e7bdb-2471-415d-9ea7-1f9d2084aa3c
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : de-DE
CurrentUICulture : de-DE
PrivateData      : NuGetConsole.Host.PowerShell.Implementation.NuGetPSHost+Commander
DebuggerEnabled  : True
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

This is not my first nuget package in my visual studio solution around 10 nuget packages.
The same issue appears wenn I try to install the package with VS NuGet Paket Manager.

Any idea how solve this problem, thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

You miss the Projectname. Try the command with your Project:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool -ProjectName PROJECTNAME
```